# Can't print from MBP running Mojave to a networked Dell 3110cn

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, macbook-pro, macos-mojave

I'm hoping you can help...

I have a Dell 3110cn plugged into the wired network and a MBP running Mojave on the WiFi, both through the same router. The MBP can hit the printer's web server and ping it just fine, but trying to set up the Dell as a printer gets me "the printer is not responding" even though it appears just fine everywhere else. Also, attempting to re-set-up the printer gets me "Unable to connect to 192.168.x.xx due to an error" (oddly, it's perfectly happy to bring up the printer's web page if I ask it to)...

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?
Thanks!

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/product-support/product/dell-3110cn/drivers  ??

Comment: i've installed the Dell drivers... it doesn't help... :(